# Как запустить программу на выполнение в линуксе?

Tags: linux

Но клик по иконке не открывает программу.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Даёте файлу право на исполнение

```
chmod +x start
```

Затем запускаете из терминала из папки программы

```
./start
```

где `start` - название программы. Либо из главного меню (клик по иконке).

Answer (score 0):

Предварительно не забудьте установить права на исполнение.

Answer (score 0):

Если дело происходит в графике, то выставляете в свойства "Пометить как исполняемый" после щелчка правой кнопкой по программе и запускаете.

Comment: в том то и дело что все они прописаны "только для чтения". А как поставить чтобы все программы запускались щелчком?

Answer (score -3):

```
chmod -R 777 /путь/к/файлу
```

или

```
chmod +X /путь/к/файлу
```

потом

```
./файл
```

Comment: Права `777` — это очень, очень плохо.